# Longest Common Prefix

Tags: python, string, while-loop, longest-prefix

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
Example:  Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
I'm new in coding and try to solve this problem (from leetcode). my way is search the shortest string between strings, here is my code, I can't figure out where did I do wrong, it seems the while loop doesn't work at all. I appreciate if someone could help me. here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        string = ""
        len_st = []
        for st in strs:
            len_st.append(len(st))
        m = min(len_st)
        prefix = strs[len_st.index(m)]
        while prefix:
            for st in strs:
                if prefix in st:
                    continue
                else:
                    prefix = prefix.replace(prefix[-1], "")
                break
            return prefix
        else:
            return ""
```

**input : ["flower","flow","flight"]**
**output: "flo"**
**expected output: "fl"**

Comment: You have a `for` loop with a `break` as its last line. This means it will only iterate once.

Comment: Same with the `while` with a `return` as its last line.

Comment: `if prefix in st:` This will be `True` if `prefix` is anywhere in `st` - not just at the beginning. You can use [startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith) instead. *Edited - fixed typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no need to loop through it manually at all. Let Python do that for you.

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    assert len(strs) > 0
    prefix = min(strs,key=len)
    while not all(s.startswith(prefix) for s in strs):
        prefix = prefix[:-1]
    return prefix
```

This uses `min()` to return the shortest word (or one if them) and chooses that as the candidate prefix. Then it checks to see if all the offered words begin with the prefix. Calling `all()` will terminate the checking at the first failure. Then it tries again with a shorter candidate prefix, until all of the words start with that, or the prefix is `''`.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach:**

1. First, we will find the shortest string and its length.
2. Secondly, we will take the first string and match each character
   with the other strings.
3. As soon as we encounter a character that does not fit, we will break out of the loop.

**Code Solution :**

```
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        // Longest common prefix string
        StringBuilder longestCommonPrefix = new StringBuilder();
        // Base condition
        if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) {
            return longestCommonPrefix.toString();
        }
        // Find the minimum length string from the array
        int minimumLength = strs[0].length();
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
            minimumLength = Math.min(minimumLength, strs[i].length());
        }
        // Loop for the minimum length
        for (int i = 0; i < minimumLength; i++) {
            // Get the current character from first string
            char current = strs[0].charAt(i);
            // Check if this character is found in all other strings or not
            for (String str : strs) {
                if (str.charAt(i) != current) {
                    return longestCommonPrefix.toString();
                }
            }
            longestCommonPrefix.append(current);
        }
        return longestCommonPrefix.toString();
    }
}
```

**Time Complexity :** O(m*n)

**Space Complexity :** O(1)